# What is the purpose of slow experience gain in Pathfinder Society Organized Play?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, experience-points, pathfinder-society

[Pathfinder Society Organized Play](http://paizo.com/pathfinderSociety) allows players to advance either 1XP or 1/2XP per session.  There are no advantages offered by taking the slower XP (experience) gain, so why would someone use this option?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The relevant bit of the *Pathfinder Society Field Guide*:

> At character creation and each time you gain a level, you decide if
>   you would like your character to be on the standard or slow
>   advancement track for the entirety of that level.

Primarily, the "slow" XP gain is so that you can keep playing with a particular character longer. Note that when you gain a level you pick whether you are on the slow or normal track for the next level. There are a couple of reasons you might do this:

**Hypothetical 1: I like playing PFS with my friends, but I attend more games than they do**

I might decide to do ½ XP for a few levels, so that I'll stay in the same tier with them.

**Hypothetical 2: I really love this character, but I'm approaching the level 12 cap too rapidly!**

I might then do ½ XP to prolong the life of that character.

**Hypothetical 3: I GM a lot of PFS games, and all of my characters are getting XP, but I've not had time to play them**

Might choose ½ XP for a level or so, in order to actually get to play the character at that level.

In the end, it's just a way to stretch out the pacing of PFS games, since there's not a lot of end-game content at level 12, and if you play a lot, you'll be leveling up fairly quickly.

Comment: Living Greyhawk didn't have this rule, and actually punished people for avoiding character retirement, and Pazio appears to just think it is silly to punish players for trying to play a beloved character a bit longer.

Comment: It is also the case that depending on where you are there may not be a lot of other players in PFS with characters at a given higher level - so you might choose slow advancement to stay at the level of play available near you for longer.

Answer (score 12):

Slow advancement also offers the additional benefits:

1. Twice as many Day Job checks (which means more free gold between games)
2. If you have the Borderland Keep vanity property, you can get **2** prestige points per slow advancement.
3. Twice as many chances to receive a Boon at the end of an adventure.
4. If you're a Druid or Ranger, twice as many chances to teach your animal companion a new trick.
5. If you're a spell caster, twice as many chances to learn a new spell from a scroll.
6. Twice as many chances to make saving throws to remove a carry-over affliction.
7. Basically, twice as many chances to do anything that is normally permitted only once between game sessions.

Answer (score 7):

I've found with newer players that the longer they play a level the better grasp they have on the class and character, as they can spend more time mastering and getting comfortable with the abilities/feats/spells.

Comment: I agree with that completely: I found LG rammed me through the levels so fast that I was still figuring out my new spells when I levelled.

Answer (score 5):

The reason I chose to do this when I played is so I can understand the classes better that I never play at a non-organized play setting.  This allows me to find the classes quirks and as a DM helped me challenge my players that played the classes I never played before.  It also helped me realize that I really enjoy the Witch class.